# React useState hook not consistently updating

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I started integrating websockets into an existing React/Django app following along with [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuM5_G4LrqY&list=PLLRM7ROnmA9EnQmnfTgUzCfzbbnc-oEbZ&index=3) (accompanying repo [here](https://github.com/justdjango/justchat/tree/master/src)).  In that repo, the websocket interface is in `websockets.js`, and is implemented in `containers/Chat.js`.

I can get that code working correctly as-is.

I then started re-writing my implementation to use Hooks, and hit a little wall.  The data flows through the socket correctly, arrives in the handler of each client correctly, and within the handler can read the correct state.  Within that handler, I'm calling my useState function to update state with the incoming data.

Originally I had a problem of my single `useState` function within `addMessage()` inconsistently firing (1 in 10 times?).  I split my one `useState` hook into two (one for current message, one for all messages).  Now in `addMessage()` upon receiving data from the server, my `setAllMessages` hook will only update the client where I type the message in - no other clients. All clients receive/can log the data correctly, they just don't run the `setAllMessages` function.

If I push to an empty array outside the function, it works as expected.  So it seems like a problem in the function update cycle, but I haven't been able to track it down.

Here's my version of `websocket.js`:

```
class WebSocketService {
  static instance = null;

  static getInstance() {
    if (!WebSocketService.instance) {
      WebSocketService.instance = new WebSocketService();
    }
    return WebSocketService.instance;
  }

constructor() {
    this.socketRef = null;
    this.callbacks = {};
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.socketRef.close();
  }

  connect(chatUrl) {
    const path = `${URLS.SOCKET.BASE}${URLS.SOCKET.TEST}`;
    this.socketRef = new WebSocket(path);

    this.socketRef.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket open');
    };

    this.socketRef.onmessage = e => {
      this.socketNewMessage(e.data);
    };

    this.socketRef.onerror = e => {
      console.log(e.message);
    };

    this.socketRef.onclose = () => {
      this.connect();
    };
  }

  socketNewMessage(data) {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    const { command } = parsedData;

    if (Object.keys(this.callbacks).length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    Object.keys(SOCKET_COMMANDS).forEach(clientCommand => {
      if (command === SOCKET_COMMANDS[clientCommand]) {
        this.callbacks[command](parsedData.presentation);
      }
    });
  }

  backend_receive_data_then_post_new(message) {
    this.sendMessage({
      command_for_backend: 'backend_receive_data_then_post_new',
      message: message.content,
      from: message.from,
    });
  }

  sendMessage(data) {
    try {
      this.socketRef.send(JSON.stringify({ ...data }));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  }



 addCallbacks(allCallbacks) {
    Object.keys(SOCKET_COMMANDS).forEach(command => {
      this.callbacks[SOCKET_COMMANDS[command]] = allCallbacks;
    });
  }

  state() {
    return this.socketRef.readyState;
  }
}

const WebSocketInstance = WebSocketService.getInstance();

export default WebSocketInstance;
```

And here's my version of `Chat.js`

```
export function Chat() {
  const [allMessages, setAllMessages] = useState([]);
  const [currMessage, setCurrMessage] = useState('');

  function waitForSocketConnection(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (WebSocketInstance.state() === 1) {
        callback();
      } else {
        waitForSocketConnection(callback);
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  waitForSocketConnection(() => {
    const allCallbacks = [addMessage];
    allCallbacks.forEach(callback => {
      WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(callback);
    });
  });


/*
 * This is the problem area
 * `incoming` shows the correct data, and I have access to all state
 * But `setAllMessages` only updates on the client I type the message into
 */
  const addMessage = (incoming) => {
    setAllMessages([incoming]);
  };

  // update with value from input
  const messageChangeHandler = e => {
    setCurrMessage(e.target.value);
  };

  // Send data to socket interface, then to server
  const sendMessageHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const messageObject = {
      from: 'user',
      content: currMessage,
    };
    setCurrMessage('');
    WebSocketInstance.backend_receive_data_then_post_new(messageObject);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      // rendering stuff here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do you process received messages from other clients?

Comment: @DrewReese Any new message comes through `addMessage()` - I can log `incoming` there correctly on every client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to rewrite everything into functional components with hooks.

**You should decompose it functionally** - main (parent, class/FC) for initialization and providing [data and] methods (as props) to 2 functional childrens/components responsible for rendering list and input (new message).

If you still need it ... `useEffect` is a key ... as **all code is run** on every render in functional components ... **including function definitions**, redefinitions, new refs, duplications in callbacks array etc.

You can try to move all once defined functions into `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {

  const waitForSocketConnection = (callback) => {
    ...
  }

  const addMessage = (incoming) => {
    setAllMessages([incoming]);
  };

  waitForSocketConnection(() => {
    ...
  }

}, [] ); // <<< RUN ONCE
```

Comment: Yes, breaking up the component up into a Class & pure component definitely works.  And was good to step back and remember that, so thank you.  I am still curious as to what causing the problem at that last step though.

Comment: new `addMessage` function definition on every render > always new fn ref, different from passed to `WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks` ?